# Finding equation of a line perpendicular to the tangent

Tags: calculus

I got a calculus question which gave us a curve, $f(x)=x^5$, and a tangent at $x = -2$. I have to find the equation for a line perpendicular to the tangent yet still going through the tangent point. So far, I got $y=(-1/16x) - 32.125$, but my book gives $0=x+80y+2562$...How does this happen ???

So far, I tried to find the slope of the tangent to $y=x^5$, and got 16, and my equation for the tangent was $y=16x$. I used it's negative reciprocal and just subbed in (-2,-32) into it to get the equation. It seems that it's wrong.

Comment: You have probably misreported the equation from the book. It looks as if it wants to be the tangent line, with a slope of $80$. If you want help, please [edit] the question to show us how you arrived at your answer. Use mathjax so we can read it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note that the derivative with respect to $x$ of $x^5$ is $5x^4$. Plugging in $x=-2$ gives us an instantaneous slope of $80$. As Ethan pointed out above, I'm not quite sure why your book gives the perpendicular line equation that way.

Comment: @Gnumbertester points out that your equation for the tangent line has the wrong slope. Moreover, it does not go through the point on the curve at (−2,f(−2)). And does the book really show y in two places in the answer?

Comment: I have arrived at how I was mistaken, thank you guys.